# How to add Countdown Timer for each Question for Quiz App using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, countdowntimer

[This is my questions table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNj2i.png)

I am trying to build a Quiz App using laravel. Now I am stuck at integrating countdown timer for each question.

I am storing time for each question in the questions table. I want to submit the first question or redirect to the next question after completion of the countdown of the first question timer. So, at last, I want to display the result with time take for each question.

Can anyone provide me a link or any reference to do that? Happy if anyone can get me out of this.

Comment: Use sessions and run javascript timer on front end. Have an extra validation of how much time spent using `time()` at your backend, just in case anyone tampered with javascript.

Comment: I am new to laravel. So can u elaborate how can i store question, answer and question time taken after hitting next next button  and display results after final submit. @vivek_23

Comment: On clicking of `next` button, you send time taken to answer and the answer itself via ajax. On click of final submit button, you compute the results from server and display results accordingly.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i had got no idea of ajax before this. Anyway 100 thanks to you. @vivek_23

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://flipclockjs.com/

Use the following callbacks to do what you need (take them to the next page)

```
var clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 100, {

  // Create a minute counter
  clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',

  // The onStart callback
  onStart: function() {
    // Do something
  },

  // The onStop callback
  onStop: function() {
    // Do something
  },

  // The onReset callback
  onReset: function() {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for giving some way to try, i will try this.